Nextjs 14 SSR deployment to Linux Redhat NGINX PM2 - Console log not showing
I have a simple NextJS 14 SSR application which I'm using typescript and app routing. I've deployed this application to my Linux Redhat server using nginx and also pm2. I use this commane to start my app: pm2 start npm --name "my-test-app" -- start
Everything is working fine except for my server component. I have added some console.log in my server component but none of these console log are printed out in the pm2 logs. I need to see the console log to do debugging. Can anyone help me on this? I'm new to NextJs.
Below is my nginx conf.
server {
listen 80;
server_name MYSERVERAPP;

location /myapp {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

location /myapp/_next {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

error_page 404 /404.html;
location = /404.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
}

Thank you in advance! :)
